# Stuck at laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I am getting a trouble in laravel.

I have a template which works. 
But at blog page, when i try to pass id to see the specific blog, the  template doesn't recognize links and scripts that are inherited from master page.

Style disappears when passing id to route.

How can be possible ?

Here are the links and scripts at  app.blade.php

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" id="brk-direction-bootstrap" href="{{ asset('css/assets/bootstrap.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" id="brk-skin-color" href="{{asset('css/skins/brk_blue.css')}}">
    <link id="brk-base-color" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/skins/brk-base-color.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/assets/offsets.css')}}">
    <link id="brk-css-min" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/assets/styles.min.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('vendor/revslider/css/settings.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('vendor/revslider/css/revolution.addon.bubblemorph.css')}}">
  @yield('content')
```

........................

> Here is post.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title')
    Post
@endsection

@section('content')
@endsection
```

Comment: You have to write ``route('post', ['id' => $post->id])`` when you want to assign a parameter to a named route. Or what kind of classes do you mean?

Comment: @Brotzka I mean links and scripts

Comment: Can you show us the complete views including sub-views?

Comment: also web.php route file

Comment: that may be beause `$post->id` would be blank

Comment: @Aleksandrs  I edited them

Answer (score 1):

If the route accepts parameters, you may pass them as the second argument to the method like this :

```
{{route('post', ['id' => $post->id]}}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-route